# How to retrieve data from an XmlNode into List

Tags: c#, xml, xmlnode

I followed the code as shown here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms429658(v=office.14).aspx

The console shows:

```
   <z:row ows_MetaInfo="5;#" ows_Level="3" ows_Title="TITLEA" ows_ID="5" />
   <z:row ows_MetaInfo="6;#" ows_Level="3" ows_Title="TITLEB" ows_ID="6" />
   <z:row ows_MetaInfo="7;#" ows_Level="3" ows_Title="TITLEC" ows_ID="7" />
```

In my c# code, I have:

```
System.Xml.XmlNode nodeListItems= getItems.GetListItems(listName,viewName,query, viewFields, rowLimit, queryOptions, null); 

foreach(System.Xml.XmlNode listItem in nodeListItems){
   Console.WriteLine(listItem.InnerXml); 
}
```

Question: How am I able to retrieve only the titles from each xmlnode (TitleA, TitleB, TitleC)?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I ended up using the code that was shown in one of these answers: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sharepoint/en-US/2c042b7b-19a5-4062-94b5-8e2ea7e117b4/how-to-get-list-item-using-webservice . Thank you everyone for helping!

Answer (score 1):

You can get it from `Attributes` like so :

```
foreach(System.Xml.XmlNode listItem in nodeListItems){
   Console.WriteLine(listItem.Attributes["ows_Title"].Value); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this :

```
listItem.Attributes["ows_Title"].Value;
```

Be sure that ows_Title attribute exist !

Answer (score 0):

try below code for getting specific attributes

```
foreach(System.Xml.XmlNode listItem in nodeListItems){
   Console.WriteLine(listItem.Attributes["ows_Title"].Value); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(saveurl);
List<string> values = new List<string>();
while (reader.Read())
{
    switch (reader.NodeType)
    {
        case XmlNodeType.Text:
            values.Add(reader.Value);
            break;

    } //switch case ends
} // while loop ends
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use the following code (from: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sharepoint/en-US/2c042b7b-19a5-4062-94b5-8e2ea7e117b4/how-to-get-list-item-using-webservice) to get my answer:

```
foreach (XmlNode node in nodeListItems)
                {
                    if (node.Name == "rs:data")
                    {


   for (int i = 0; i < node.ChildNodes.Count; i++)
                            {

                            if (node.ChildNodes[i].Attributes != null)
                            {
                                string field = node.ChildNodes[i].Attributes["ows_Title"].InnerText;

                             }
                        }
                    }
                }
```